pdf.js supplied data is not a valid base64-String in angular
I am converting a div to a pdf with the code below. It works fine on desktop (Crome, Edge, Safari, ...) it wokrs on Android mobile device but fails in IPhone safari works on Chrome on IPhone, also works on Safari in IPAD:
  savePdf(){
    const div = document.getElementById("pdfReport");
    console.log('getting div', div);
    const fileName = "ponudba.pdf";
    const options = {backgroundColor: "white", height: div.clientHeight, width: div.clientWidth, useCORS: true};

    html2canvas(div, options).then((canvas) => {
      const pageWidth = 208;
      const imgHeight = canvas.height * pageWidth / canvas.width;
      const imgWidth = pageWidth;
      var position = 0;
        //Initialize JSPDF
        console.log('Initialize JSPDF');
        let doc = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");
        //Converting canvas to Image
        console.log('generate image from div');
        let imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg",0.3);        
        //Add image Canvas to PDF
        console.log('Add image Canvas to PDF');
        doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight); // it breaks here
        console.log('get blob');
        const data = doc.output('blob');

    });    
  }

Error:

Any Idea what I am doing wrong?

you have a warning: "canvas area exceeded the maximum limit" -
have you tried to reduce the height/width?

yes I saw that will work on this next days and see if it solves the problem
